# Openblas does not link to Scipy

Tags: python, scipy, debian, openblas

I am currently running scipy on Debian Jessie. I have installed scipy from apt-get. I have also installed blas and lapack from apt

```sh
sudo apt-get install python-scipy libblas-dev libatlas-dev
```

Then I have compile openblas on my machine and install it in the default path: /opt/OpenBLAS/

I have updated the alternatives, and everything seem to be fine:

```sh
 sudo update-alternatives --list libblas.so.3
/opt/OpenBLAS/lib/libopenblas.so

sudo update-alternatives --config liblapack.so.3
Il existe 2 choix pour l'alternative liblapack.so.3 (qui fournit /usr/lib/liblapack.so.3).

  Sélection   Chemin                          Priorité  État
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/lapack/liblapack.so.3   40        mode automatique
* 1            /usr/lib/lapack/liblapack.so.3   40        mode manuel
  2            /usr/lib/liblapack.so            40        mode manuel
```

However, when I am computing dot product with scipy it seems to not use Openblas, while if I am calling directly the dgemm function it seems to be good. I use the following code:

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
from scipy import linalg
import time
from scipy.linalg.blas import dsyrk,dsymm,dgemm

n = 1000

#  Data generation
x = sp.random.rand(n,n)
x += x.T
x /= 2


# Dot product
ts=time.time()
xn = np.dot(x,x)
print 'numpy dot product ',time.time()-ts

ts=time.time()
xs = sp.dot(x,x)
print 'scipy dot product ',time.time()-ts

ts=time.time()
xss = dgemm(1.0,x,x)
print 'openblas dot product ',time.time()-ts

# eig
ts=time.time()
[E,v]=np.linalg.eigh(xss)
print 'numpy eig ',time.time()-ts

ts=time.time()
[E,v]=linalg.eigh(xss)
print 'scipy eig ',time.time()-ts
```

```sh
python test_openblas.py
numpy dot product  2.31659698486
scipy dot product  2.34038615227
openblas dot product  0.0457999706268
numpy eig  2.27925086021
scipy eig  0.384080886841
```

All my programs use sp.dot() rather than dgemm and sp.dot() works well on other machines (ubuntu or debian ones). If someone has some inputs/solutions, it would be very nice ! Any help too !